# How to bind the src attribute of a webview element?

Tags: electron, svelte

I am trying to bind the src attribute of a `webview` element in svelte, but it is erroring out saying src is not a valid binding.

REPL link: https://svelte.dev/repl/0fd95800646a46aa9691c74e5b12cb98

Code:

```
<script>
    let url=""
</script>

<webview bind:src={url}></webview>
```

This is the webview tag for electron

Answer (score 0):

`webview` is *not* a standard HTML element, you cannot use it in the REPL at all. If you want something that works everywhere, use an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

(If this is the `webview` from Electron, it would only ever work there.)

Comment: This is about the webview tag of electron.

Comment: But it still doesn't work in my electron app.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are trying to use a non-standard element instead of just an `iframe`?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to make a web browser in svelte with electron, and iframes don't support most sites.